# Django LTRIM function usage with custom char

Tags: django-models

Is there a way to pass in the character/s that we want to trim to the LTRIM function.

```
from django.db.models.functions import LTrim
ModelA.objects.filter(a__startswith="0").update(a=LTrim("a"))
```

Relevant SQL

```
UPDATE "modlea" SET "a" = LTRIM("modela"."a") WHERE "modela"."a"::text LIKE '0%';
```

This will trim white spaces to the left, but how to remove "0" to the left with Django ?

The SQL for it is

```
UPDATE "modlea" SET "a" = LTRIM("modela"."a", "0") WHERE "modela"."a"::text LIKE '0%';
```

But what is the Django equivalent ? Was trying with the below, but it is not working.

```
ModelA.objects.filter(a__startswith="0").update(a=LTrim("a", "0"))
```

It fails with

```
TypeError: 'LTrim' takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

So how to pass `0` to the `LTrim` function in Django ?

Comment: No, you want to remove the leading zeros once?

Answer (score 1):

Given you want to remove leading zeros, you could work with a [**`REGEX_REPLACE(…)`** <sup>[mariadb]</sup>](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/), this is not a function that Django has, but we can use a [**`Func`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

MyModel.objects.filter(my_field__startswith='0').update(
    my_field=Func(
        F('my_field'), Value('^0+'), Value(''), function='REGEX_REPLACE'
    )
)
```

Depending on the database backend, the function might have a different name.